# How do i Add sound correctly?

Tags: java

ok so im working on my program which will play a song once a button is clicked, i have the code down, and my audio is playing when the button is clicked,but the only problem now is that my program is going completely bonkers and just playing the audio when the button is clicked!!!! the program just freezes the audio keeps playing but the program will not do it's other functions! What am i doing wrong? and how do i fix it?

heres the code for the action listeners button

in myFrame.java

```
sound sound = new sound();
private File pokemonBattle = new File(".\\audio\\"+"sound.wav");


private void dualButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)       
    {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    for (int i = 0; i<1; i++){
    c = deck.getNextCard();
    p1hand[i] = c;
    p1.setCard(c);                   //ignore all this
    c = deck.getNextCard();
    p2hand[i] = c;
    p2.setCard(c);
     }

    pokemon1.setEnabled(true);
    pokemon2.setEnabled(true);
    pokemon1.setIcon(p1hand[0].getImage()); //ignore all this as well
    pokemon2.setIcon(p2hand[0].getImage());
    textArea.setText("Pokemon 1:"+p1hand[0].toString()+"\nPokemon 2:   
 "+p2hand[0].toString());
    p1ResultLabel.setText("");
    p2ResultLabel.setText("");

      //this is where im calling my audio
     sound.playAudio(pokemonBattle);//this is where im calling my play audio method

 }
```

sound.java where i have playAudio()

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;



public class sound {

public void playAudio(File sf){
    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

    try
    {
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sf);
        audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        System.out.println(audioFormat);

        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new  
  DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,audioFormat);

        sourceDataLine =(SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

        byte tempBuffer[]=new byte[100000];
        int cnt;
        sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine.start();
        while((cnt=audioInputStream.read
                     (tempBuffer,0,tempBuffer.length))!=-1){
            if(cnt>0){
                sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer,0,cnt);
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play the audio in a separate thread. The program becomes unresponsive because it is playing your audio on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) instead of drawing the UI and responding to user interaction.

instead of:

```
sound.playAudio(pokemonBattle);
```

do:

```
Thread t = new Thread( new SoundPlayer( sound, pokemonBattle );
t.start();
```

and also:

```
public class SoundPlayer implements Runnable
{
    private final sound sound;
    private final File soundFile;

    public SoundPlayer( sound sound, File soundFile )
    {
        this.sound = sound;
        this.soundFile = soundFile;
    }

    public void run()
    {
       sound.playAudio( soundFile );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm completely confused How exactly would I play the audio in a seperate thread?

Answer (score 0):

Joseph is right. But in this instance the problem is

```
 while((cnt=audioInputStream.read
                     (tempBuffer,0,tempBuffer.length))!=-1){
            if(cnt>0){
                sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer,0,cnt);
            }

        }
```

You while loop will run infinitely hence freezing up your application. Since you are reading and writing the entire buffer at once there is no need for the while loop. Do this outside of a loop and you will be fine.